# Chrome Extension: Call content script when needed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension and got an issue here. Is there a way to call content script when needed? Couldn't find a workaround about it.

```
run_at: 'document_idle'
```

didn't help.

EDIT: `run_at` at `document_start` starts in the beginning, `document_end` after loading. Content script loads automatically all the time, no way to execute it when needed.

Comment: when is "when needed"? please provide some more details

Comment: @NoamHacker, done

Comment: what about calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript` ? (see [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript))

Comment: You should read the "[Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)" section of the "[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)" documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to run a script in a webpage when you need it.

For example:

**background.js**

```
if (needed == true) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:"myContentScript.js"},function(){
        console.log("run when needed");
    });
}
```

Comment: I would if that was easy... but is there a way to inject CSS to the `myContentScript`?

Comment: You can use [`chrome.tabs.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS)